# Where is the application.properties file in a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I started a new Spring boot project, I want to change the port number and I read that I have to modify the `/resource/application.properties` to do so.

I cannot locate this file however, did I miss something? Do I need to install a boot starter? I don't want to set this using the spring CLI.

Should I create this file manually? If so, I think I'll have to mark this file as the properties file somewhere in the code. Where would that be?

Comment: You should create file manually if no exists manually

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You will need to add the `application.properties` file in your classpath.

If you are using Maven or Gradle, you can just put the file under `src/main/resources`.
If you are not using Maven or any other build tools, put that under your src folder and you should be fine.

Then you can just add an entry `server.port = xxxx` in the properties file.

Comment: First I want to thank for your answear. I tried this, but it does not work for me. Tomcat even starts with a random port.

Comment: I started a new project with java spring boot. And here it works.

Comment: If you want to add directly to a WAR, just place it under /WEB-INF/classes/

Answer (score 27):

You can create it manually but the default location of application.properties is here

[image]

Comment: Yes even I agreed that this(src/main/resources/app.yml) is the default location for application.yml (or application.properties). But recently I am working on Kotlin with SPringboot and I discovered (while working on Junits) that its expecting the app.yml to be present at "test/resources/config/application.yml" and NOT at "test/resources/application.yml" - when did this change come ? Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 24):

You can also create the application.properties file manually.

SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations and add them to the Spring Environment:

- A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
- The current directory
- A classpath /config package
- The classpath root

The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).
(From [the Spring boot features external configuration doc page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files))

So just go ahead and create it

Answer (score 5):

In the your first journey in spring boot project I recommend you to start with Spring Starter [Try this link here](https://start.spring.io).

[image]

It will auto generate the project structure for you like this.application.perperties it will be under /resources.

**application.properties important change**, 
 
 
server.port = Your PORT(XXXX) by default=8080 
 
server.servlet.context-path=/api (SpringBoot version 2.x.) 
 
server.contextPath-path=/api (SpringBoot version < 2.x.)

Any way you can use **application.yml** in case you don't want to make redundancy properties setting.

**Example** 
application.yml

```
server:
   port: 8080 
   contextPath: /api
```

application.properties

```
server.port = 8080
server.contextPath = /api
```

Comment: How to access let's say from any class the port variable?

Answer (score 0):

application.properties file is present in src/main/resources/application.properties if it is not presen yo can create your own file

Example

```
server.port=9091
student.postgres.db=postgresdburl
```

How to consume - student.postgres.db -> value in your code

```
@Value("${student.postgres.db}")
private String jdbcUrl;
```

I hope this can solve your query let me know if still you are not able to access the property file