# SpringBoot can't read application.properties when running outside jar folder

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created a SpringBoot Application, and I placed the application.properties in the same folder of the jar file. This is the content of the file:

```html
server.port=8081
```

When I run /bin/java -jar /opt/apl/org.web.exemplo-java-maven.1.0.0-90/org.web.exemplo-java-maven-1.0.0-90.jar outside the jar folder it doesn't read the application.properties and runs the program in port 8080.

When I run /bin/java -jar /opt/apl/org.web.exemplo-java-maven.1.0.0-90/org.web.exemplo-java-maven-1.0.0-90.jar inside the jar folder (or inside any folder with the application.properties) it reads the file and runs in port 8081.

What is happening? I thought the properties file needed to be in the same place of the jar file. But it happens that it needs to be in the same folder where I'm running the command.

Comment: It behaves this way because that's how it's supposed to behave, as documented: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files. It took me 30 seconds to find that information. Much less than it took you to write your question. Read and search the documentation. It helps a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775194/where-is-the-application-properties-file-in-a-spring-boot-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention at application startup Spring Boot looks for the `application.properties` file at classpath root, e.g. top-level of directory structure in your JAR file. You can customize this behaviour and configure a different `application.properties` location using a Spring specific environment property when starting the application from cmdline:

```
/bin/java -jar /opt/apl/org.web.exemplo-java-maven.1.0.0-90/org.web.exemplo- 
java-maven-1.0.0-90.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/other- 
application.properties
```

Check this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: So, if I need to use the same property that is in my app folder, i can just do that?: --spring.config.location=classpath:/opt/apl/org.web.exemplo-java-maven.1.0.0-90

Comment: @EduardoDias you should use --spring.config.location=file://.... instead of classpath:/

read spring docs for details => https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources