# Why isn't Heroku recognising the correct Java version when I've told it explicitly?

Tags: java, heroku, heroku-cli

Upon `git push heroku master` on my spring-maven-java project the Heroku cli recognises it is a Java project and attempts to build it. It prints that it is installing *JDK 1.8* and after much terminal output it says `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project myProject: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 10.0.2`

The maven-compiler-plugin configuration source and target explicitly identifies Java 10.0.2 as specified as acceptable by Heroku documentation, and `java.runtime.version=10.0.2` is in both `application.properties` and `system.properties`

I presume I need to get Heroku to install the correct JDK at the start. How do I get Heroku to get and use Java 10?

**See aso the extent to which I've tried modifying** `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>10.0.2</source>
        <target>10.0.2</target>
        <release>10.0.2</release>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604111/heroku-cannot-deploy-java-11-spring-boot-app My thread, still haven't figure it out and I tried a lot of things, nothing worked. It has to be something else.

Comment: @valkon in my case `system.properties` was in the `src` directory instead of the root/highest level directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `system.properties` file in the root directory of your app, and put the following in it:

```
java.runtime.version=10.0.2
```

Commit it to Git and push again. For more info see [Heroku'd Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions).

Comment: Thanks, I now have a different problem but moving my `system.properties` file from `resources` to the root/highest level directory has fixed the JDK and made Heroku run the app

Comment: I assumed `system.properties` would go in the same place as `application.properties` which is [recomended to go in src/main/resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38775319/7394417)