# Spring : What's the difference if I put an application.yml in config or in resource folder?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I searched a lot on spring website but didn't find the answer, I noticed sometimes we put application.yml in /resource, sometimes under /config so what is the difference?

Comment: See relevant answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775194/where-is-the-application-properties-file-in-a-spring-boot-project

Comment: Hi I checked that post but that did not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Other than the order in which the files are looked for/loaded, I believe there is no actual difference for Spring. This flexibility is so the code can be run in different environments without needing to change the actual code, [as stated in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.0/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config). If anything, using one over the other is probably to fit the developers taste, as Spring automatically transforms YAML notation to .properties notation ([although this is from early documentation. I can't tell if this works as it used to](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml)) if SnakeYAML libarary is present.